# jquery bubble pop up on updation of content not working

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery bubble pop up  , the code is as below,

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
           //create bubble popups for each element with class "button"
           $('.button').CreateBubblePopup({
                  selectable: true,
              innerHtmlStyle: {
               color:'#333333', 
              'text-align':'center'
              },

              themeName:    'green',
                  position: 'right',
                  themePath:    'images/jquerybubblepopup-theme'
        });
     });
```

and element which shows bubble pop ups are normal div elements 
with class as button ( check above code)

so let's say i have three div elements with class as button and 
three distinct ids as

_1
_2
_3

and my code which sets bubble pop up for them is as follows

```
$('#_1').SetBubblePopupInnerHtml('Hi Bubble 1');
$('#_2').SetBubblePopupInnerHtml('Hi Bubble 2');
$('#_3').SetBubblePopupInnerHtml('Hi Bubble 3');
```

this works fine,

but now problem is ,
when page get a jquery response  i recreate the div elements (with class as button as ids as _1,_2,.._n) with updated contents and i also need updated contents for their respective bubble pop ups,

so now to get updated contents of bubble pops ups , I modified code as follows

```
var bcontents = new Array();

bcontents[0] = 'Hi Bubble 1';
bcontenst[1] = 'Hi Bubble 2';
bcontenst[2] = 'Hi Bubble 3';
```

and then

```
 $('#_1').SetBubblePopupInnerHtml(bcontents[0]);
 $('#_2').SetBubblePopupInnerHtml(bcontents[1]);
 $('#_3').SetBubblePopupInnerHtml(bcontents[2]);
```

So when i get jquery response , i recreate divs class as button and ids as _1,_2 ... . along with this , i am modifying the contents of  bcontents array  also , but i am not getting the jquery bubble pop up for updated contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call **CreateBubblePopup** again after you recreate div.button.

Comment: Cool, it's working ,  again i also need to call SetBubblePopupInnerHtml    , i was trying to attach that call with "live"  , anyways, calling again working , thanks for the help

Comment: your solution is working fine with chrome and firefox but not working in IE